Energy-optimal downclocking of multiple machines
It's a fairly common situation when we get a fractional number of machines. For example, this alumina setup, with only 'pure alumina' recipe, has nice numbers everywhere except '1.5x Refinery' for Aluminum Scrap:

I can overclock one refinery by 1.5x, using up significantly more energy, or I can use two, and downclock... and now comes the big question:

downclock one to 50%, or
downclock both to 75% ?

I know with overclocking, due to exponential nature of the power curve of overclocked machines, overclocking two machines to 150% is better than leaving one at 100% and pushing one to 200%. But I'm lacking the sense of how that works for downclocking. Which approach gives better power savings?

If you're like me, you overclock/underclock and forget ;)

@TimmyJim If I prepare  blueprint of a production unit (raw resources -> complex product), I'm obsessive about making it clocked perfectly. Otherwise I just slap an 8x constructor blueprint or two and let them sort it out.

I don't know anything about this specific game but a simple approach to this general problem is to just double the amount of machines in each component. Then everything is an integer and you get twice as much output (and need twice as much input).

The article on Production Amplifier which is a 1.0 feature and so very likely the article is up-to-date, gives the following formula for power of amplified building:

(that fancy exponent is  - producing a logarithmic scale that crosses 1 but gives 2.5 power usage at 2x speed)
With no Sommersloops, the Power multiplier is 1.
Power usage with 2x 75% downclocked machines:
2*(0.75 ^ 1.321928) = 1.367...
Power usage with 1 100% and 1 50% downclocked machine:
1 + (0.5 ^ 1.321928) = 1.4
That means downclocking all machines equally gives better power utilization than downclocking one.
The graph on Satisfactory Wiki Clock Speed page seems to be up-to-date despite being uploaded in 2022:


With no Sommersloops, the Power multiplier is 1. I thought Sommersloops didn't change the power consumption of a machine?

@TimmyJim They don't change input resource consumption, while increasing the output. They massively increase power consumption - 'fully looped-up' machine has quadruple the consumption of regular!

@TimmyJim I can confirm that Sombersloops, at least in a manufacturer increase power consumption. At max overclock, and sombersloops inserted, one manufacturer will use ~740MW!

@tuskiomi i thought that's how much they used when fully overclocked.  I might want to go check my factory a bit then lol

There is no bottom to this barrel (up to the limit of sig-figs on the machine interface). If you need 1.5 total production (2*0.75, or 1+0.5) you can partition among as many machines as you want and the power consumption will always decrease. 3 machines at 50% each uses 1.2 total power. 4 at 37.5% uses 1.094 total power, 50 machines at 3% each uses only 0.485 total power. The downside, of course, are the additional space, construction time, and startup times required! :)

FWIW, I think symmetric clocking among the minimum required number of machines is a sensible stopping place, though.

@do-the-thing-please Unless you have blueprints :) Like, I need 2 constructors, it's literally faster and easier for me to drop my 2-floor 8-constructor manifold blueprint than to build and hook up two constructors adding splitters, mergers, power for both. :)

@TimmyJim 55MW @ 100% 0 sommers; 184.68MW @ 250%, 0 Sommers; 220MW 100%, 4 sommers;  738.72MW @ 250% 4 sommers. It's a 13.43x power usage multiplier for max upgrade.
